# Is assigning dimensions to a div converts it's position to relative?

Tags: html, css

I have learned so far that if an element position is set to absolute it will be relative to the first non-static element and if there isn't it will be relative to the document itself, so by chance when i'm trying to test how z-index rule works i wrote this simple code:

```css
.static {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
  z-index: 1;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="static"></div>
<div class="absolute orange"></div>
<div class="absolute yellow"></div>
```

And as you can see i have given dimensions to the`.static` class, but the result is that the absolutely positioned elements still relative to the static one. and this changes if i removed the static element's dimensions.

So is that means that dimensions have changed the div position property to non-static.

**Update**

I have found that if offsets applied top the absolute elements it will relative to the document, but i am confused because it should be positioned at top most left corner by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`position: absolute;` makes an element relative to the first non-static **ancestor**. There's no hierarchy to your `<div>`s, so they are relative to the document, *but so is your static* `<div>`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

> **absolute**
>
> The element is removed from the normal document flow; no space is created for the element in the page layout. Instead, it is positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor if any; otherwise, it is placed relative to the initial containing block. Its final position is determined by the values of top, right, bottom, and left. This value creates a new stacking context when the value of z-index is not auto. Absolutely positioned boxes can have margins, and they do not collapse with any other margins.

Notice the part in the middle, "*otherwise, it is placed relative to the initial containing block.*" The orange and yellow `<div>`s will sit on top of each other because they are positioned absolutely, but below the static one as you haven't defined any other offsets for them.

If you want to force your absolute boxes to the top left, you should also set `left: 0;` and `top: 0;`.

Comment: thanks, but it's first non-static ancestor in this case should be the document and also the document is the initial containing block, so why both yellow and orange `div`s are still inside the normal flow, shouldn't they be relative to the document forgetting about the static .. i think i still missing the point

Comment: If you are using Google Chrome or another browser that supports developer tools, open them up and inspect your rendered elements. The document itself is really the `<html>` tag. You'll see that if you hover over your `<body>` or <`html`> tags, they have a maximum height (dictated by the static box). Your absolutely positioned divs are underneath that, they are relative to it and sit below it (as if they were still in flow) because no other offsets were specified. To really see the effect, add one more static div to the top. Does that make more sense?

Comment: I think we are getting closer..but I need you to read the last comment on @Quentin's answer

Answer (score 1):

> I have found that if offsets applied top the absolute elements it will relative to the document, but i am confused because it should be positioned at top most left corner by default.

No, they shouldn't.

The default values for `top` and `left` are `auto` not `0`.

The element is taken out of normal flow, but positioned where it would be if it was in normal flow (although without influencing the position of subsequent elements, which is why the orange element is covered by the yellow element)

Comment: thanks, but also the `relative` position according to my understanding  takes the element out of normal flow, but positioned where it would be if it was in normal flow isn't it!

Comment: After a lot of searching i have found you answer is the closest one, but needs more explanation, which the `absolute` position has many cases, the first one is using `absolute` only without offsets then offsets defaults to `auto` and the element is taken out of normal flow, but positioned where it would be if it was in normal flow(as you mentioned), but if offsets are defined it will be measured relative to the document if no positioned ancestors or to the first positioned parent (first none static parent) if there is any.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like it is defaulting to the top-left corner. If an element is position absolute, it positions itself relative to the nearest PARENT which is non-static. There are no parent divs in your HTML. Everything is a sibling.

Comment: thanks, but If no parents it should be defaulting to the document